# How to use OTG cables for NEXUS4 without rooting

Tags: nexus-4, usb-on-the-go

Is it possible to use OTG Cables for Nexus-4 without rooting the device? Can Nexus Media Importer work with OTG cables for Nexus4?

Answer (score 4):

The Nexus 4 does not support USB-On-The-Go. From the [Nexus Media Importer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeysoft.nexususb.importer&hl=en) description on Google Play it states that:

> Due to hardware limitations, the Nexus 4 is not supported.

The only way to get it to work is to root and install a custom ROM and/or kernel. You will also need a usb y cable as the Nexus 4 cannot provide the necessary 5 volts. [Android Central](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-advanced-usb-otg-nexus-4) has a page with more information

Comment: Will the same be supported with NEXUS 7.